# Print visual as grayscale WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

How can I print a visual as grayscale without actually showing the PrintDialog, e.g.

```
PrintDialog dialog = new Dialog();
dialog.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), printerNameAsString);
dialog.PrintTicket.InputBin = InputBin.AutoSelect;
// Further settings, e.g. PageMediaSize and scaling the visual.    

dialog.PrintVisual(myVisual, "myDescription");
```

Can I somehow get the PrinterDialog to print the visual in grayscale? Or is there a completely other way to achieve a grayscale printout of my visual?

Edit: myVisual (the Visual I want to print) is a Grid, so it inherits from UIElement.
Edit 2: If possible I would prefer not to use any external libraries (because of company policies).

Comment: is your `myVisual` inherited from `UIElement`?

Comment: @KingKing yes, it is actually a Grid.

Comment: I use the dll provided here: http://bursjootech.blogspot.nl/2008/06/grayscale-effect-pixel-shader-effect-in.html

Comment: @Bizz Thanks for the link, if possible I actually would prefer not to use external libraries...

Comment: if it helps: the source is also available there. However I couldn't manage to compile it because of some software requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PrintDialog the OutputColor can be set:

```
myPrintDialog.PrintTicket.OutputColor = OutputColor.Grayscale;
```

Also, the PrintCapabilities make it possible to actually check which OutputColors are possible:

```
PrintCapabilities capabilities = myPrintDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(myPrintDialog.PrintTicket);
ReadOnlyCollection<OutputColor> possibleColors = capabilities.OutputColorCapability;
```

On the hardware available to me this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the standard lib in `Microsoft.Expression.Effects` assembly. The effect here is `MonochromeEffect`. Just apply this effect before printing your visual:

```
myVisual.Effect = new MonochromeEffect();//make grayscale
dialog.PrintVisual(myVisual, "myDescription");
myVisual.Effect = null; //turn it off
```

You have to import the library I mentioned above and add this using instruction:

```
using Microsoft.Expression.Media.Effects;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I was hoping for a way of somehow directly telling the printer to print in grayscale... (and then let the printer handle the "effect"). Well, if this should turn out to be impossible then your solution shows a nice way of achieving the goal.

Comment: @Daniel I don't think the PrintDialog supports such feature. Also the library I mentioned is not some kind of external or third-party. It's a standard library from Microsoft. You can also make your own library to apply a grayscale effect but it requires more work.

Comment: @Daniel you couldn't find that library in the reference list (when importing)?

Comment: After checking I found out that I probably would need the Blend SDK to reference the Microsoft.Expression.Effects assembly. I guess I can go that way. It just seems strange to me that there is no other way, after all printing in grayscale is a pretty "normal" feature of a printer... also, I'm not completely sure if printing a grayscale image is exactly the same as telling the printer to print in grayscale (however, I'm not an expert in printing, it may well amount to the same).

Comment: Thanks again for your help, after searching around I somehow did find a property on the PrintTicket of the PrintDialog with which I can set the printing to grayscale.

Comment: @Daniel well, that name (`PrintTicket`) does not make sense but it's really useful in this case, thanks for notifying me about that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem where DrawString would always print solid black--even though the Brushes specified a lighter shade. I finally discovered that by placing an image onto the graphics object, it would print lighter shades that were in the image. It feels like a hack, but it works! (The printdialog solution might have worked too--I don't know since I'm printing automatically from a service where there is no printdialog.)